# How do you have unique ListView elements in Xamarin, while also using RecycleElement?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xaml, xamarin

**Outline of functionality:** I have a ListView that uses RecycleElements in Xamarin. The ListView is made up of large images, with a little heart ImageButton on top of each item. When the heart is clicked to favourite the image, it turns from white to red.

**Problem:** When I click a heart inside item 0 and then scroll down, item 4 will also have a red heart - which should not happen. This is due to the ListView using RecycleElements.

**What I need:** The heart ImageButton must be unique for each item in the list, while also allowing me to keep RecycleElements as the CachingStrategy to improve performance. The heart needs to unique as it shouldn't show every 5th item in the list as being favourited.

Is there a way of having the ImageButton be unique, while also being able to use RecycleElements? Or is there a work-around that would allow something like this? I haven't been able to come up with a solution.

**XAML:**

```
<ListView x:Name="MealsListView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding Meals}" ItemTapped="OnMealItemClicked"
                  CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" SeparatorVisibility="None"  HasUnevenRows="True" Grid.Row="0">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <StackLayout Margin="15,10,15,30" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                <Frame CornerRadius="5" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                       HeightRequest="500" WidthRequest="1000" Padding="0" IsClippedToBounds="True">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
                                </Frame>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <ImageButton ClassId="HeartButton" Clicked="OnHeartClicked" Source="heartWhite_64x64.png" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                   HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" Margin="310,-50,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" 
                                   Margin="15,-30,15,40" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5"/>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

**C#:**

```
private void OnHeartClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // change enabled state
            m_enableHeart = (m_enableHeart == true) ? false : true;
            ImageButton heartImage = (ImageButton)sender;

            // change heart colour
            if (m_enableHeart)
            {
                // show red heart
                heartImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("heartRed_64x64.png");
            }
            else
            {
                // show white heart
                heartImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("heartWhite_64x64.png");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?

[image]

I use two images to make a test. Add a I add a `Isfavourite` property in model, If the `Isfavourite` is true I set the Image to `hamburger` ， if the `Isfavourite` is false I set the Image to  `Clover`. In the  Layout.xaml I use `Command` to achieve it in `ImageButton`, here is `ImageButton` code.

```
<ImageButton Source="{Binding Image}" 
             Command="{Binding BindingContext.ChangeImage, Source={x:Reference Name=mylistview} }"  
             CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                               Aspect="AspectFill"
                               HeightRequest="150"
                               WidthRequest="150"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"  />
```

Here is my layout code.

```
   <ListView x:Name="mylistview" ItemsSource="{Binding persons}"   CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" SeparatorVisibility="None"  HasUnevenRows="True" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell >
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Frame HasShadow="True"
                                   BorderColor="DarkGray"
                                   CornerRadius="5"
                                   Margin="20"
                                   HeightRequest="300"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               FontSize="Large"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                    <ImageButton Source="{Binding Image}" Command="{Binding BindingContext.ChangeImage, Source={x:Reference Name=mylistview} }"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                               Aspect="AspectFill"
                               HeightRequest="150"
                               WidthRequest="150"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"  />

                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>

                        </StackLayout>


                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>
```

Here is layout background code.

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
           InitializeComponent();


            this.BindingContext= new PersonsViewModel(Navigation); 


        }
    }
}
```

Here is viewModel code.

```
  public class PersonsViewModel
    {


        public ObservableCollection<Person> persons { get; set; }

        public ICommand ChangeImage { protected set; get; }

        public PersonsViewModel(INavigation navigation)
        {

            persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
            persons.Add(new Person() { Name=  "Leon1" ,Image= "Clover.png", Count=1 , Isfavourite=false});
            persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Leon2", Image = "Clover.png", Count = 2 , Isfavourite = false });
            persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Leon3", Image = "Clover.png", Count = 3 , Isfavourite = false });
            persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Leon4", Image = "Clover.png", Count = 4 , Isfavourite = false });
            persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Leon5", Image = "Clover.png", Count = 5, Isfavourite = false });
            persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Leon6", Image = "Clover.png", Count = 6 , Isfavourite = false });
            persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Leon7", Image = "Clover.png", Count = 7, Isfavourite = false });
            persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Leon8", Image = "Clover.png", Count = 8 , Isfavourite = false });
            persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Leon9", Image = "Clover.png", Count = 9 , Isfavourite = false });
            persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Leon10", Image = "Clover.png", Count = 10 , Isfavourite = false });


            ChangeImage = new Command<Person>((key) =>
            {
                var person = key as Person;

                 person.Isfavourite = !person.Isfavourite;

           //    m_enableHeart = (m_enableHeart == true) ? false : true;

                if (person.Isfavourite)
                {
                    // show red heart
                    person.Image = "icon.png";
                }
                else
                {
                    // show white heart
                    person.Image = "Clover.png";
                }

            });

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my model code.

```
    public class Person: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        bool _isfavourite = false;
        public bool Isfavourite
        {
            get
            {
                return _isfavourite;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_isfavourite != value)
                {
                    _isfavourite = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Isfavourite");

                }
            }

        }


        bool _changed =false;
        public bool Changed {
            get {
                return _changed;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_changed != value)
                {
                    _changed = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Changed");

                }
            }

        }

        public int Count { get; set; }
        string name;
        public string Name
        {
            set
            {
                if (name != value)
                {
                    name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Name");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
        }

        string image;
        public string Image
        {
            set
            {
                if (image != value)
                {
                    image = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Image");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return image;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
}
```